# Python r.listen(source) work in IDLE but not in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, speech-recognition

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source: 
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=2)
    #audio = r.record(source,duration=3)
    print("say something")             
    audio = r.listen(source)              
    print("got it")

    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
        print('You said: ' + command + '\n')    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
    except LookupError:                            # speech is unintelligible
        print("Could not understand audio")
```

I try to run the above code in IDLE and it worked fine. However, when I try to run it in VS Code, it got stuck in 'audio = r.listen(source)'. Basically, the microphone can't listen to anything.

I have the same environment chosen in my VS Code and have all packages installed.

- I am using a mac. When running in IDLE, it requested for microphone access, but visual studio code does not (can't manually grant access to it either).

I tried running the same thing in windows and it is working fine (in both IDLE and VSCode)

Comment: Is it exactly the same environment or did you try to replicate the same environment? Basically if it's the former I have no clue, but if it's the latter there is the potential of version drift with what was installed.

Comment: @BrettCannon Yeap, it is the exactly same environment.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas as VS Code and the extension don't touch hardware like your microsphone. Last guess is setting `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false`, but this only has an effect on non-Windows OSs.

Comment: @BrettCannon Sorry that I left this important part out --> I am using a Mac VSC. Nevertheless, I checked on the terminal.integrated.inheritEnv and it is set to True.